# How to get Web Content by Structure name in Liferay Portlet?

Tags: liferay, structure, portlet

I need to get all Web Content created with a specific Structure in a jsp portlet.

I try to use structureName but this throw a excepcion

```
ClassLoader cl = PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader();
DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class, cl)
        .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("structureName").eq("Empresa"));
List <JournalArticle> journalArticles = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);
```

How i get the web content by structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the structureId field when query journalarticles and passing the structureKey as value like this way

```
DynamicQuery dynamicQueryStructure = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(
                DDMStructure.class).add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("name").like(
                "%>Empresa</Name>%"));

        List<DDMStructure> structures = DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQueryStructure, 0, 1);
        if(!structures.isEmpty()) {
            String structureKey = structures.get(0).getStructureKey();
            ClassLoader cl = PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader();
            DynamicQuery dynamicQuery = DynamicQueryFactoryUtil.forClass(JournalArticle.class, cl)
                    .add(PropertyFactoryUtil.forName("structureId").eq(structureKey));
            List<JournalArticle> journalArticles = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.dynamicQuery(dynamicQuery);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to construct dynamic queries and fiddle with class loader, `JournalArticleService` can do that.

See [`JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil#getStructureArticles(groupId, dmStructureKey)`](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portlet/journal/service/JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.html#getStructureArticles(long,%20java.lang.String)).